# Looking for a good Mini - Panels tutorial

Tags: panels, 7, views

There are lots of good to tutorials for view and panels, but I'm having trouble finding specific information on how to properly use mini panels. Does anyone know of a good tutorial or explanation of how it works? again I've seen to referenced a bunch of times as a possible solution to certain problems, but never really understood how to use it.

(D7 panels 3 would be ideal)

Comment: Asking for tutorials is off topic here on DA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not found a tutorial specifically for mini-panels, but it works similarly to page panels.  nodeone.se has an [excellent tutorial](http://dev.nodeone.se/node/770) on using Page Panels (Page Manager & Panels modules enabled).

Mini Panels are closely related , but behave more like blocks.  When you define a mini-panel it will be available in the panels UI for placement as well as in the admin/structures/blocks form.  The major difference from blocks is that mini-panels are smart.  They can take context from the node, user and other sources and display accordingly.  They also connect to a View.

There is one thing to observe when defining a mini-panel.  The UI is slightly different from Page Panels and the first time I used them, I could not figure out how to add content to one.  To access the "content" and other setting forms select the Panels breadcrumb  menu at the top.

Comment: Thanks, I think the point of confusion was show to get to the settings and content portion of the mini-panel, I would got to "edit" and only see the overview, once I noticed the breadcrumbs I understood, The UI is different from a regular panel so it a wee bit confusing

Comment: I entered an issue at Drupal/Panels about this yesterday.  Hopefully they will make it a bit clearer in the next go-around.

Answer (score 2):

Although for panels2, [here](http://lyphuong10.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/panels-2-creating-a-mini-panel-and-passing-arguments-through-context/) is a basic tutorial for minipanels.
Current panels adds some stuff, but the idea is illustrated well.