# field collection items are not in panels

Tags: panels, entities

Im trying to use Panels to display a Field collection but it looks like it is not in the overlay (see screenshot). How can I display the field collection in my panels?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the method depends on what you are trying to achieve by doing this.

- You could write a [plugin for panels](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33336/what-are-ctools-plugin-content-type-access-etc-and-how-does-one-create-them) to make it recognise field collections.
- It looks like [Fieldable Panels Panes](https://www.drupal.org/project/fieldable_panels_panes) *might* help.
- You could use [mini-panels](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18868/looking-for-a-good-mini-panels-tutorial) to wrap the fields (part of panels)
- You could just put the fields up individually

Hope this helps, without your intended use-case in your question it is difficult to provide a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Panels 7x 3.9 got built in support for field collection items, guess it was a later addition, available now as form and node elemens.

it's not obvious at first, since the collections are listed with "field:..." same as normal fields.

saw it due to the habbit of "prefixing" all field collection items with fc_ (field_fc_name) makes 'em stand out a bit more.

Hope it helps, good luck to all ;)